# Lightning: createComponent function does not work, but doesn't throw error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error

A while now I've been trying to get this code to work:

```
var destination = "markup://c:TZ_Tab_" + tabId;
var ctxId = component.get("v.contextId");

$A.createComponent(destination, {contextId:ctxId},
                       function(view, status, errorMessage) {
                            var content = component.find("tabContent");
                            content.set("v.body", view);
                       });
```

This is the code in the view where the component should show:

```
<div aura:id = "tabContent"/>
```

I tried to debug and show the status / errorMessage, but it doesn't seem to reach the callback function.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no problem with your code (I am assuming that there is a component named TZ_Tab_1, where 1 is the tabId). If there is any issue with your callback, browser will throw a callback failed warning message. I can be more helpful, if I had access to your components code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Due to security reasons I can't give you access to the code. What I've noticed is that after the click the callback does not fire yet, but after the second click it finishes the callback and loads the component.

Comment: I meant sharing the code snippet here on the post, not the actual access.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, no error in JS, and component is not appearing on page. Is it a bug? I'm using $Lightning.createComponent()

Comment: This is all there is to it. What more code de you want to see? I have it working now in combination with the aura:locationChange event. The sad thing is that this  doesn't work in IE. For IE I am trying to use window.onhashchange event, but this causes the createComponent function to break. Could this have something to do with the secure window? See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_window.htm